# Phonegap - Android - Select Popup Font Size

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, phonegap

can i change the font size for  pop up in phonegap (android)?

The word should not break.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css

```
word-break: normal;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipse;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:2vmin;
```

Comment: where you add this css?

Comment: select {
word-break: normal;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipse;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:2vmin;
}